# Doing mongoimport programmatically

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am using the system command:

`mongoimport -db mydb --collection mycollection --file my.json` to do an import of a big JSON dump into Mongo.  Now, I am using a Mongo Grails plugin to connect my web application to Mongo. Is there anyway I can run the import from Grails?  I was thinking of just getting Grails to run a system command but if my Grails Server is on a different box to my Mongo instance this will mean I need mongo installed on the Grails server.  I was hoping to avoid this.

Mongo plugin I am using is: `:mongodb:3.0.1`

Any tips appreciated?

Comment: You could build up the process with your own program or you could just install the tools package to your app server and run the external command. Mongoimport can be found in [mongodb-org-tools](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-a-specific-release-of-mongodb) or some variant depending on your system

Answer (score 0):

Write a controller/service that uploads/parses the json file and issues the `insert` commands. You can also convert the json data into your domain classe instances and do the saving with proper validation.

If this task should be fired only once, I'd use a groovy script evaluator to run the script that does the import. I'm using something like http://grails.org/plugin/scripting .